# Material slider wrong drag label show

Tags: android, slider, rangeslider

If I use material slider example from [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/slider/) range slider when drag looks like this:
[image] 
But when I use it i my application, when I drag slider I see only one slider label:
[image][image]

How can I fix it? My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"

    android:focusable="true"

    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    tools:context=".presentation.sub_search.view.SubSearchFragment">


    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/prices_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:stepSize=".1"
        android:valueFrom="0"

        android:valueTo="100" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
Slider pricesSlider = view.findViewById(R.id.prices_slider);
pricesSlider.setValues(10f, 70f);
```

UPD:

I have this problem only inside fragments. If I use the same code in activity, I have no problems

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti 1.2.0-alpha06. I check with 1.2.0-alpha05, the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fragment container. After I change container to CoordinatorLayout problem fixed. In other place problem fixed after I replace ViewPager with ViewPager2

Comment: I'm having the same issue and am not sure how to fix it. Can you post some code with this answer for myself and others who happen to have the same issue?

Comment: Also using 1.2.0-alpha06

Comment: @cren90 add example in new answer

Answer (score 0):

@cren90 for example in this code

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new SliderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

slider_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            android:id="@+id/prices_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="100"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You need replace FrameLayout with androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout in main_activity.xml